# How do i get the ID of a slash command and mention it?

Tags: discord, discord.js

I want to get the ID of a discord slash command to make a simailar thing that MEE6 has: (discord.js)

> Help:
> `/help` `[command]`

This makes you able to click on the slash command this is displayed inside of the message!

How do i do this?
I think it is `</help:[ID of the slash command]>`
Is this correct?
I've tried it but it didn't work...
Please help!

Answer (score 10, accepted):

To get the slash commands ID you right click the [dark box](https://i.stack.imgur.com/e7XGm.png) above the chatbox and press copy ID if that doesn't come up make sure Developer Mode is on under Settings > Advanced

To actually mention the slash command you use this syntax `</name:id>`

Comment: Thanks for this! Any clue if the built-ins have IDs? Nothing shows up on click for them